# Bash: Batch Rename Appending File Extension

Tags: regex, bash, csv, terminal

I have a bunch of temperature logger data files in .csv format. The proprietary temp-logger software saves them with weird useless names. I want to name the files by their serial numbers (S/N). The S/N can be found in each of the files (in several places).

So, I need to extract the S/N and change the name of the file to {S/N}.csv.

I'm almost there, but can't figure out how to get the ".csv" file extension onto the end.

Here's my code:

```
for i in *.csv; do  grep -Eo "S\/N\: [0-9]+" "$i" | cut -c 6- | head -1 | xargs mv "$i" ; done
```

Note the "cut" and "head" commands are necessary to get just the S/N number from the regular expression return, and to take only one (the S/N is listed several times in the file).

If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'd love to see it. All I really need though is to get that ".csv" onto the end of my new file names.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `xargs`, but it's simpler to skip it and call `mv` directly. (You're only renaming one file per call to `xargs` anyway.)

```
for i in *.csv; do
    ser_num=$(grep -Eo "S\/N\: [0-9]+" "$i" | cut -c 6- | head -1)
    mv "$i" "$ser_num.csv"
done
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much. Don't know why I was trying so hard to keep piping.